# C#: Why doesn't it delete the data from the arraylist when I press the delete button in the datagridview?

Tags: c#

When I click the delete button in the datagridview, it deletes the row but does not delete the array list.

[image: image here]

```cs
ArrayList sepet = new ArrayList();
ArrayList sepetisim = new ArrayList();
ArrayList sepetkg = new ArrayList();
ArrayList sepetfiyat = new ArrayList();
```

```cs
private void guna2DataGridView3_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 4) {
        //For Delete
        if (MessageBox.Show("Silmek İster misin", "Soru", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes) {
            
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in guna2DataGridView3.SelectedRows) {
                guna2DataGridView3.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                sepet.Remove(guna2DataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                sepetisim.Remove(guna2DataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
                sepetkg.Remove(guna2DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
                sepetfiyat.Remove(guna2DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: ArrayList is deprecated. Use List<T> instead! You may want to change to order to move  the Rows.RemoveAt to the last position.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is a [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections) that's [non-generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics).
The method [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.remove?view=net-6.0) determine [equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons) by calling `object.equals`, and it's a leaner operation `O(N)` if you want to constantly look things up by value I suggest using a different collection like [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) or [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0), also, I'd use generic collection to avoid things like [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) it hurts the performance of the application and it introduces unnecessary [memory allocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/).

As to the issue in question, two possibilities:

1. You are removing the row and the trying to access its columns and removing their values that does not exists anymore
2. You are trying to remove not a primitive type, that a call `object.equals` becomes a reference comparison which is going to never be true.